# Why doesn't my Karabiner modification show up in the Add rule sheet?

Tags: karabiner

I made this complex modification for Karabiner

```
{
    "title": "change_to_qwerty",
    "rules": [
        {
            "description": "Change input source to QWERTY while left_command is held down.",
            "manipulators": [
                {
                    "type": "basic",
                    "from": [ 
                        { 
                            "key_code": "left_command",
                        }
                    ],
                    "to": [
                        {
                            "key_code": "left_command",
                            "select_input_source": {
                                "input_source_id": "com.apple.keylayout.US"
                            }
                        }
                    ],
                    "to_after_key_up": [
                        {
                            "key_code": "left_command",
                            "select_input_source": {
                                "input_source_id": "com.apple.keyboardlayout.Programmer Dvorak$"
                            }
                        }
                    ]
                }
            ]
        }
        {}
    ]
}
```

and put it into ~/.config/karabiner/assets/complex_modifications
but it doesn't show up. I thought maybe it's because the file has errors but I can't find one.
Please someone tell me how I can make the modification show up in the "Add rule" window

Answer (score 0):

I guessed at first glance (and tested it) that your "from": expression has a set of "[“ … "]" brackets too much   –     ***NOT allowed here!***         Only in "to": and "to_ …": expressions are they ***mandatory***.

Further on: if your "key_code": is not followed by another one (or "modifiers":) *NO comma must be set.*

```
 "from": {                               << no "[" bracket
           "key_code": "left_command"    << no ","
         },                              << no "]" bracket
   "to": [
           {
             "key_code":  …
```

*(The lonely pair of brackets "{}", 3rd line from bottom, certainly isn't necessary either, is it ?)*